# Accessright and ownership Powershell

Tags: powershell

Any thoughts on how to add owner information in the following script?

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\DFSRoots\DFS\Folder_Redirection" -Recurse | ?{
   $_.PsIsContainer } | %{ $Path = $_.FullName
   # Include inherited rights from the report 
   (Get-Acl $Path).Access | Select-Object `
   @{n='Path';e={ $Path }}, IdentityReference, AccessControlType, `
   InheritanceFlags, PropagationFlags, FileSystemRights } | Export-CSV "C:\exported\Permissions4.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner is not a property of the `Access` property returned by Get-Acl, so you need to capture this before diving into the Access properties.

```
$dfsPath = "C:\DFSRoots\DFS\Folder_Redirection"
$report  = "C:\exported\Permissions4.csv"

$result = Get-ChildItem $dfsPath -Recurse -Directory| ForEach-Object { 
    $folderPath = $_.FullName
    $acl        = Get-Acl -Path $folderPath
    $owner      = $acl.Owner
    $ownerSid   = $acl.Sddl -replace 'O:([S\-\d]+).+','$1'
    $acl.Access | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Path'; Expression = { $folderPath }}, *, 
                  @{Name = 'Owner'; Expression = { $owner}},
                  @{Name = 'OwnerSid'; Expression = { $ownerSid}}
}  

# output on console
$result

#output to CSV file
$result | Export-CSV $reportPath -NoTypeInformation
```

As bonus, the above also retrieves the owners SID

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Theo, i found out other way but this one also works, now the whole point of this is to get an csv, make modification to users and add it back to the ACL, untill that point im good, but now i cant change the owner, the acl but the owner, no error, no message, this is the script im running:

> ```
> $par = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Permisionlist\PermissionsTDNA.csv" foreach ( $i in $par ) { 
> $path= $i.Path
> $Owner= $i.Owner
> $IdentityReference= $i.IdentityReference
> $AccessControlType=$i.AccessControlType
> $InheritanceFlags= $i.InheritanceFlags
> $PropagationFlags=$i.PropagationFlags
> $FileSystemRights=$i.FileSystemRights
> echo $path $IdentityReference, $Owner
> $acl = (Get-Item $path).GetAccessControl('Access')
> $aclowner = (Get-Item $path).GetAccessControl('owner')
> $permission = $IdentityReference, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType
> $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
> $Setowner = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount $Owner
> $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
> $aclowner.SetOwner($Setowner)
> $acl | Set-Acl $path
> }
> ```

Comment: I think you need to set the owner to the `$acl` object, not the `$aclowner`